# a joptionpane with a textbox and a button

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I want a joptionpane with a textbox and a button and when click on the button perform my own functions

Comment: What is a "textbox". I'm not aware any any component with that name in Swing.

Answer (score 5):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package org.life.java.so.questions;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Jigar
 */
public class InputDialog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Input:");
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want a modal JDialog with a JLabel or a JTextArea and a JButton.

Comment: With add(myButton) or getContentPane().add(myButton). It is a top level container very similar to a JFrame.